# How to submit readme.txt file in wordpress directory

Tags: plugins

Hello i created a wordpress plugin and submit to wordpress directory,
i got an email that my plugin approved but the problem is i've no readme.txt file so its not visible for public,
I wants to know how to submit readme.txt after approval ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the readme.txt to your trunk directory and commit the changes.
Its covered in the [plugin Developer FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/faq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Subversion repository for committing changes after your first contribution. You should receive login information for that, and there's a guide explaining the process over here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/